# how can i store Foreign id in user table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my Controller:-

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registor(User_CV cvfiles, User_CVviewModel cvmodel, User_Account useraccount,RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    int count = 0;
                var file = cvmodel.Cv_Path;

                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/CV"), fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        count++;

                        db.User_CV.Add(new User_CV
                        {
                            Cv_Path = Request.Files[0].FileName
                        });

                        db.User_Account.Add(new User_Account {
                            //Cv_ID = model.Cv_ID,
                            Full_Name = model.Full_Name,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            Contact_No = model.Contact_No,
                            Password = model.Password,
                            Fuctional_Area = model.Fuctional_Area
                        });
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");   
            }
            else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.");
                }
            return View(model);
            }
```

Here is My Model:-

```
 public class RegisterModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
            public string Full_Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            [Remote("Registor", "ApplicantAcc", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email already exists. Please enter a different Email.")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Contact No")]
            public string Contact_No { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Functional Area")]
        public string Fuctional_Area { get; set; }
        public int Cv_ID { get; set; }
        public string Cv_Title { get; set; }
        public string Cv_Defualt { get; set; }
        public string Cv_Path { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my View:-

```
@model _24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.RegisterModel

    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Registor", "ApplicantAcc", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="alert-danger1" id="abc">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"")
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Full_Name, new { @placeholder = "Full Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Full_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   ...........
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cv_Path, new { @id = "cvfile", @type = "file", @name = "filename", @value = "Upload", @placeholder = "Full Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cv_Path, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <button type="submit" value="Create">create</button>
                    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="Login">Sign In</a></p>
                    }
                </div>
    </div>
```

I want to send cv_id into user table,it goes null, please anyone help me.i tried through hidden fields but i don't really know about hidden fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 db.User_Account.Add(new User_Account
                                {
                                    Full_Name = model.Full_Name,
                                    Email = model.Email,
                                    Contact_No = model.Contact_No,
                                    Password = model.Password,
                                    Deptt_Id =model.Deptt_Id, 
                                });                       
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                User_Account useraccounts=  db.User_Account.Where(j => j.Email == model.Email).SingleOrDefault();
                                db.User_CV.Add(new User_CV
                                {
                                    Cv_Path = Request.Files[0].FileName,
                                    User_Id = useraccounts.User_Id,
                                    Cv_Title = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName)
                                });
                                db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the SaveChanges after you add the User_CV. Then the Id will be filled.

```
db.User_CV.Add(new User_CV
{
   Cv_Path = Request.Files[0].FileName
});
db.SaveChanges();

db.User_Account.Add(new User_Account {
     //Cv_ID = model.Cv_ID,
     Full_Name = model.Full_Name,
     Email = model.Email,
     Contact_No = model.Contact_No,
     Password = model.Password,
     Fuctional_Area = model.Fuctional_Area
});
 db.SaveChanges();
```